# Optimal ways to fine-tune pretrained tensorflow api (SSD mobilenet)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I am currently fine tuning an ssd mobilenet v2 model to improve the human detection.

My ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_config code is:

```
# SSD with Mobilenet v2 configuration for MSCOCO Dataset.
# Users should configure the fine_tune_checkpoint field in the train config as
# well as the label_map_path and input_path fields in the train_input_reader and
# eval_input_reader. Search for "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED" to find the fields that
# should be configured.

model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 1
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      ssd_anchor_generator {
        num_layers: 6
        min_scale: 0.2
        max_scale: 0.95
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 3.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.3333
      }
    }
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 300
        width: 300
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      convolutional_box_predictor {
        min_depth: 0
        max_depth: 0
        num_layers_before_predictor: 0
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 0.8
        kernel_size: 3
        box_code_size: 4
        apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
        conv_hyperparams {
          activation: RELU_6,
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.00004
            }
          }
          initializer {
            truncated_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.03
              mean: 0.0
            }
          }
          batch_norm {
            train: true,
            scale: true,
            center: true,
            decay: 0.9997,
            epsilon: 0.001,
          }
        }
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'ssd_mobilenet_v2'
      min_depth: 16
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      use_depthwise: true
      conv_hyperparams {
        activation: RELU_6,
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.00004
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            stddev: 0.03
            mean: 0.0
          }
        }
        batch_norm {
          train: true,
          scale: true,
          center: true,
          decay: 0.9997,
          epsilon: 0.001,
        }
      }
    }
    loss {
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid {
        }
      }
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      hard_example_miner {
        num_hard_examples: 3000
        iou_threshold: 0.99
        loss_type: CLASSIFICATION
        max_negatives_per_positive: 3
        min_negatives_per_image: 3
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 1e-8
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 24
  optimizer {
    rms_prop_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.004
          decay_steps: 800720
          decay_factor: 0.95
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
      decay: 0.9
      epsilon: 1.0
    }
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "D:/Databases/Coco/cctv/tf/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/model.ckpt"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type:  "detection"
  # Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we
  # empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This
  # effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will
  # never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
  num_steps: 200000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    ssd_random_crop {
    }
  }
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "D:/Code/Image/cctvmodel/tfrecordfinalALL/train2.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "D:/Code/Image/cctvmodel/label_map.pbtxt"
}

eval_config: {
  num_examples: 8000
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  max_evals: 10
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "D:/Code/Image/cctvmodel/tfrecordfinalALL/test2.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "D:/Code/Image/cctvmodel/label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

The config file is setup for retraining. To run the config file I use the following code:

```
(tensorflow) c:\models-master\research>python object_detection/legacy/train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/model2/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v2_2.config
```

For fine tuning I am referring to [tutorial 1](https://xiaoyuliu.github.io/2017/12/08/ubuntu-local-tensorflow-finetune/). Its states that to fine tune a model, the following needs to be done:

1) Create an object detection training pipeline.config file: Modify one from `/path/to/pretrainedModels/faster_rcnn_resnet50_lowproposals_coco_2017_11_08/pipeline.config`, simply changing `num_classes, fine_tune_checkpoint, num_steps, label_map_path and tf_record_input_reader/input_path.`

2) Set the correct value for `from_detection_checkpoint`. If you are fine-tuning from a pre-trained object detection model, set it to true; if from a classification pre-trained model, set it to false.

3) Use the following command to train:

```
From the tensorflow/models/research/ directory
python object_detection/train.py \
--logtostderr \
--train_dir=${PATH_TO_TRAIN_DIR} \
--pipeline_config_path=${PATH_TO_YOUR_PIPELINE_CONFIG}
```

I noticed many tutorial are very similar to the one listed above. However, the instruction does not seem to fully example optimal fine tuning process. If one had to consider how fine tuning is done in Keras its quiet flexible and elaborate.

For example, how does on state the layers that need to be freeze and specify which subsets of layers should be trained. In addition, which are the optimal conditions for SSD mobile net v2 , since model differ. In most cases, the upper layers are frozen and the last 5 layers are fine tuned.

That said, do we add in a dropout layer etc. However, how would this be achieved using the config files.

What additional parameters need to be set to optimize fine tune?

That said, there is another example that does fine tuning via python notebooks [tutorial 3](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-path-tensorflow-slim/9781491986820/video305032.html). Which is the optimal way?